# NodeJS Bin Access is denied

Tags: javascript, node.js

#### Details

I am creating a simple CLI to download music from youtube and apply spotify metadata to it. But while trying to use the binary I am having issues which I don't really understand. I'm kinda new to NodeJS, I tried to find a solution but I couldn't. Any help is appreciated

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "spot-dl",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Download music from Spotify.",
  "main": "spot-dl.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm start",
    "start": "node spot-dl.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "spotify",
    "music"
  ],
  "author": "Giant427",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "node-id3": "^0.2.3",
    "spotify-web-api-node": "^5.0.2",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "youtube-sr": "^4.2.0",
    "yt-converter": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "bin": "spot-dl.js"
}
```

`terminal`

```
C:\Users\<MY_NAME>\Documents\spot-dl>npm install -g .

added 1 package, and audited 3 packages in 693ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\<MY_NAME>\Documents\spot-dl>spot-dl
Access is denied.
```

#### Node.js version

v16.13.1

#### Example code

Not applicable.

#### Operating system

Windows 11

#### Scope

`bin`

#### Module and version

Not applicable.

Comment: Does your js file start with `#!/usr/bin/env node` ?
Also have you tried running the Terminal as an administrator?
Could you try changing the bin entry to an actual file path e.g. `"bin": "./spot-dl.js"`

Comment: Js file did not start with `#!/usr/bin/env node` I added that and also changed the file path, it all works flawlessly now, thanks you so much for your health :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your app to be executable, you have to do multiple things,
the `npm -g .` command does not move your project to your `/bin` directory, which means that you can not execute it from the terminal this way.

first, add the shebang line at the very top (the first line) in your entry file as follows:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
// the rest of your code
```

now, this file works on most Linux/Unix operating systems, if you're on a Linux/Unix based operating system, do the following:

- give the permissions to become executable:

```
chmod +x ./<YOUR_ENTRY_FILE>
```

If you're on windows, add the following in your package.json file:

```js
"bin": "./YOUR_ENTRY_FILE" // for your case it's "bin": "./spot-dl.js"
```

Now, the package can be run on windows and on Linux, the "bin" part of the package.json, Npm will check to see if it is installed on windows and it will install a .cmd wrapper alongside your script so users can execute it from the command-line.

**Edit*: for your case, your entry file is the *spot-dl.js* file.**